# Splitting an Array into firsts and lasts

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
@main = connection.execute("select code_ver, comment from mastertest
```

@main contains something like this :

```
{ [2.1, abcd],
  [3.0, xyz],
  [2.0, pqr] }
```

I want to split this array into 2 arrays such that:

```
@arr1 = {[2.1],
         [3.0],
         [2.0]}

@arr2 = {[abcd],
         [xyz],
         [pqr]}
```

I do something like this to copy one array from another one:

```
@arr1 = Array.new
@main.each { |r| @arr1.push(r[0]) }

Can something be done here itself to split it how I want it?
```

Comment: Those with `{...}` are not arrays. They are not even valid Ruby objects.

Comment: Do you really want `@arr1` and `@arr2` to be arrays of single-element arrays? It seems like a strange thing to do, and with your notation it's hard to tell whether you meant this or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there were some typo's in your "array" above, a simple `map` will do the trick:

```
> @main = [[2.1, 'abcd'], [3.0, 'xyz'], [2.0, 'pqr']]
# => [[2.1, "abcd"], [3.0, "xyz"], [2.0, "pqr"]] 
> @arr1 = @main.map {|y|[y[0]]}
# => [[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]] 
> @arr2 = @main.map {|y|[y[1]]}
# => [["abcd"], ["xyz"], ["pqr"]]
```

You might also look at `transpose`:

```
> @main.transpose
# => [[2.1, 3.0, 2.0], ["abcd", "xyz", "pqr"]]
```

Comment: Your second answer does not give the intended result.

Comment: Understood.  That's why I suggested _looking_ at it.  After all, the arrays of single-element arrays are a little wonky.

Answer (score 1):

you might try:

```
ar1 = Array.new
ar2 = Array.new
[ [2.1, abcd], [3.0, xyz], [2.0, pqr] ].each do |val| 
  ar1 << val[0]
  ar2 << val[1]
end
```

edit:
as mentioned:

```
{[2.1, abcd], [3.0, xyz], [2.0, pqr]}
```

isnt't valid, and its my solution is not returning an array of single item arrays

Comment: -1. This gives `[2.1, 3.0, 2.0]` etc. instead of `[[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@arr1, @arr2 = @main.transpose.map{|a| a.map{|x| [x]}}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `map`? Isn't a simple `transpose` sufficient?

Comment: @AndyH Without `map`, you will get `[2.1, 3.0, 2.0]` etc. Not `[[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to do two `map` operations:

```
@arr1 = @main.map(&:first)
@arr2 = @main.map(&:last)
```

but if `@main` is large this is a bad idea because it traverses the array twice. In that case:

```
@arr1 = []
@arr2 = []
@main.each do |item|
  @arr1 << item.first
  @arr2 << item.last
end
```

`transpose` can be done in a one-liner

```
@arr1, @arr2 = @main.transpose
```

Comment: -1. This gives `[2.1, 3.0, 2.0]` etc. instead of `[[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]]`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something using the `#transpose` method:

```
main = [[2.1,'abcd'],[3.0,'xyz'],[2.0,'pqr']]
p main.transpose.first #=> [2.1, 3.0, 2.0]
```

Alternatively, if the result should be single-element arrays:

```
main = [[2.1,'abcd'],[3.0,'xyz'],[2.0,'pqr']]
p main.transpose.first.map { |e| [e] } #=> [[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]]
```

Comment: -1. This gives `[2.1, 3.0, 2.0]` etc. instead of `[[2.1], [3.0], [2.0]]`.

Comment: @sawa It's hard to tell from the question whether that is desired or not, since the asker seems unfamiliar with ruby syntax.  I've added an example that produces single-element arrays, although it is well covered by the other answers now.